# Get Azure File share size using PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell

is there a way to use powershell to get the size of an Azure File share?

I can use the Get-AzStorageShare to pull the etag, quota, tier, etc. but I can't seem to find where to get the "usage".

I can see it in the portal so it must come from somewhere...

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `Get-AzStorageUsage`?

Comment: From what I can tell the Get-AzStorageUsage module is high level and provides info at the region, not down to a specific resource like an Azure File Share.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of version 7.5 of Azure PowerShell, there is no Cmdlet in `Az.Storage` module which would give you this information directly.

However, there is a workaround.

The idea is to call `Get-AzStorageShare` which will give you an object of type [`AzureStorageFileShare`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.files.shares.shareclient?view=azure-dotnet). This object has a property called [`ShareClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.files.shares.shareclient?view=azure-dotnet) which is available in Azure Storage File SDK. Once you have access to this object, you can call [`GetStatistics`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.files.shares.shareclient.getstatistics?view=azure-dotnet#azure-storage-files-shares-shareclient-getstatistics(azure-storage-files-shares-models-sharefilerequestconditions-system-threading-cancellationtoken)) method to get the share usage.

```
$accountName = "your storage account name"
$accountKey = "your storage account key"
$shareName = "your share name"
$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $accountName -StorageAccountKey $accountKey
$share = Get-AzStorageShare -Name $shareName
$client = $share.ShareClient
# We now have access to Azure Storage SDK and we can call any method available in the SDK.
# Get statistics of the share
$stats = $client.GetStatistics()
$shareUsageInBytes = $stats.Value.ShareUsageInBytes
Write-Host $shareUsageInBytes
```

Answer (score 1):

Great answer from @Gaurav Mantri, I just wanted to state here (since I don't have enough reputation to comment his answer).

I've attempted all the possible options and this one is the most accurate.

Previously I've tried to use Get-AzMetric, however it not only has intermittent issues and sometimes doesn't bring results but also only provides the sum of all capacity used and wouldn't be useful for multiple file share scenarios:

```
(Get-AzMetric -ResourceId "$($storageaccount.id)/fileServices/default" -MetricName "FileCapacity" -AggregationType Total).Data.Total
```

I've tried adding a -MetricFilter, but this doesn't filter as intended and have no result:

```
New-AzMetricFilter -Dimension FileShare -Operator eq -Value $share.Name
```

Thus my ended up being like this:

```
if ($Resource.PrimaryEndpoints.file) {
$shares = $Resource |Get-azStorageShare
foreach($share in $shares) {
    $usage   = $share.ShareClient.GetStatistics()
    $usageGB = [math]::Round(($usage.Value.ShareUsageInBytes / 1024 / 1024 / 1024),1)
    $MinimumFreeGB = $share.Quota * ($Config.FileShareFreePercentage/100)

    if (($share.Quota - $usageGB) -lt $MinimumFreeGB -and ($share.Quota -ne 0 )) {
        Write-Host "File share '$($share.Name)' free space is lower than $($Config.FileShareFreePercentage)%"
    } else {
        Write-Host "File share '$($share.Name)' free space is greater than $($Config.FileShareFreePercentage)%"
    }
}
```

}